# Add Multiple Auto links for textArea dynamically in appcelerator

Tags: textarea, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, autolink

I want to add multiple auto links for text area dynamically But if the textarea is not editable links are not working,I have a textarea in that i am tagging users when i tag user,that tagged user needs to become the autolink.here i am tagging multiple users when i clicking on that user name it will goes to his profile wall.

I have tried with attributesString for textArea but it dynamically not adding the auto links.Please help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

With "dynamically" do you mean "automatically"? I'd suggest you use AttributedString and then use a [helper lib like this](https://github.com/FokkeZB/Tracker/blob/master/app/lib/utils.js#L14) to add the links for you.